# How to prevent floating-point being implicitly converted to integral value at function call in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++

How to prevent floating-point being implicitly converted to integral value at function call?

```
#include <iostream>

void fn(int x) {
    std::cout<<"fn("<<x<<")\n";
}

int main() {
    std::cout<<"Hello, this is 301014 :)\n";
    fn(2);
    fn(3.5);
    return 0;
}
```

Here the outputs are 2 and 3 respectively.
I am compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 31014.cpp -o 31014 -v`. And there is no mention of **3.5** being converted to **3**.
Is there a way to prevent, or atleast detect, this?

Kindly help me out, please.

Comment: `-Wconversion` or `-Wfloat-conversion` will give you a warning. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

**Method 1**: You [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) the function template `fn` by using `std::enable_if`.

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value>::type fn(T x) {
    std::cout << "fn(" << x << ")\n";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, this is 301014 :)\n";
    fn(2);       // works
    // fn(3.5);  // won't work;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bEGPh9Whf)

---

**Method 2**: Alternatively, [delete the functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) using `=delete`, which shouldn't take place in
template deduction.

```
void fn(int x) {                          // #1
    std::cout << "fn(" << x << ")\n";
}
template<typename T> void fn(T) = delete; // #2

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, this is 301014 :)\n";
    fn(2);      // works  using #1
    // fn(3.5); // won't work since it uses #2
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yf9MK3Esj)

Answer (score 5):

Another way to solve this is to add `template<typename T> void fn(T)=delete;` (also works with older c++ standards):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> void fn(T)=delete;

void fn(int x) {
    std::cout<<"fn("<<x<<")\n";
}

int main() {
    std::cout<<"Hello, this is 301014 :)\n";
    fn(2);
    fn(3.5); // now gives error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I would prefer, because it does not force me to implement the function taking `int` as a template.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to prevent implicit conversion.

1. Using `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same`.

   ```
   template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,int>,bool> = false>
   void func(T x) {
       cout << x << endl;   
   }
   ```
2. In C++ 20, one can use [`requires`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires)

   ```
   template <class T>
        requires std::same_as(T,int)
   void func(T x) {
      // ....
   }
   ```
3. Using [`concept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints).

   ```
   template <class T>
   concept explicit_int = std::same_as<T,int>;

   void func(explicit_int auto x) {
      // ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Enable the right compiler warnings.**

GCC and Clang call this warning `-Wconversion`.

With this flag, I get:

```
<source>:10:8: warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'int' changes value from 3.5 to 3 [-Wliteral-conversion]
    fn(3.5);
    ~~ ^~~
```